# Why do I get different results for the Isolation Forest after using PCA?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, dimensionality-reduction, autoencoders, anomaly-detection

I am working on an **unsupervised** anomaly detection project and used the Isolation Forest and AutoEncoders (a normal one and a VAE) to detect anomalies. The AutoEncoders' prediction are identical but are different than the Isolation Forest's prediction. 
Since I a have One-Hot-Encoded dataset which has 200 features I wanted to visualize the data by using PCA for dimensionality reduction (down to two dimensions).

Out of curiosity I used the Isolation Forest on the new, lower dimensional dataset and got completely different results and I do not understand why. Does the Isolation Forest not work on datasets transformed by PCA? Furthermore, is it possible for the Isolation Forest and an AutoEncoder to have completely different results when it comes to detecting anomalies ? Since it is unsupervised, I cannot measure the accuracy etc.

Comment: In what way are the results different? Can you provide a plot? Or a CSV with the inputs and outputs, and the code used? Without knowing these things, people can only guess as to what is going on with your data

Comment: But PCA after One-Hot-Encoding make zero sense - is that actually what you did?

Comment: My bad! I get different datapoints as anomalies than before the dimensionality reduction. I cannot provide a plot or data itself since it is corporate data. Why doesn't PCA make sense after One-Hot-Encoding ?

Comment: Would it make sense to use an AutoEncoder as a dimensionality reduction method for One-Hot-Encoded data?

Comment: PCA is designed to operate on continuous, dense data. One-hot-encoded data is discrete and sparse.

Comment: What is your data originally, before one-hot-encoding?

Comment: It is mixed data, 42 features mostly being cagetorical (only about 10 are numerical) coming from finance. Some numerical features have a high variance since there a some zero values and some extreme high values (which cannot really be seen as outliers).

Comment: You can try a categorical embedding like Cat2Vec, https://openreview.net/pdf?id=HyNxRZ9xg 
This converts the categorical variables to continuous ones

Comment: I will have a look at it thank you!